# Called CAMetalLayer nextDrawable earlier than needed

Tags: ios, swift, metal

The GPU frame capture is warning:

```
your application called CAMetalLayer nextDrawable earlier than needed
```

I am calling `present(drawable)` after all my other GPU calls have been made, directly before committing the command buffer

```
guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
let computeBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
let descriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }

...

//First run the compute kernel
guard let computeEncoder = computeBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else { return }
computeEncoder.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState)

dispatchThreads(particleCount: particleCount)

computeEncoder.endEncoding()
computeBuffer.commit()

//I need to wait here because I need values from a computed buffer first 
//and also why I am not just using a single pipeline descriptor
computeBuffer.waitUntilCompleted() 

//Next render computed particles with vertex shader to a texture
let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor0)!
renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
...
renderEncoder.endEncoding()

//Draw texture (created above) using vertex shader:
let renderTexture = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor)
renderTexture?.setRenderPipelineState(renderCanvasPipelineState)
...
renderTexture?.endEncoding()

//Finally present drawable and commit command buffer:
guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else { return }
commandBuffer.present(drawable)
commandBuffer.commit()
```

I don't see how it is possible to request the currentDrawable any later. Am I doing something wrong or sub-optimal?

I started looking into the issue because most frames (basically doing the same thing), the wait for the current drawable is about 3-10ms. Occasionally the wait is 35-45ms.

I see a number of recommendations to use `presentDrawable` instead of `present`, but that does not seem to be an option with Swift.

Is there any way to request the current drawable when it is needed and make the warning go away?

Comment: What's `descriptor0` and where and how is it initialized?

Comment: My bad! I moved obtaining the render pass descriptor to just above where desciptor0 is used, not just above descriptor (that's what I get for using undescriptive var names!). Thanks - the warning is all gone now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `view.currentRenderPassDescriptor` at the top of the code you listed. The render pass descriptor has to have a reference to the drawable's texture as a color attachment. That implies obtaining the drawable and asking for its texture. So, that line requests the drawable.

Don't obtain the render pass descriptor until just before you create the render command encoder (`let renderTexture = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor)`) using it.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Good to know. I did as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same warning in Frame capture. Any ideas?